# advantages and disadvantages of domain registrars on a blockchain

Tags: eth-domain

The idea of having a domain registrar on a blockchain goes back to Aaron Swartz (I think). Lately, there is a tweet by Udi Wertheimer in which he suggests that it might be a bad idea. It makes me wonder: What are the advantages and disadvantages of having a domain registrar on a blockchain?

The search results I get on Google don't seem to be especially critical of the idea.